# Aspectj with spring aop configuration xml

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop

I'm working in an application which uses Spring, version 3.1.1, and now I need to add some aspects to it. The aspects are written in aspectj language without annotations. I have read the spring docs [chapter 8.8](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.1.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html), but I'm struggling to make it work.

My spring configuration looks like:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true">
  <aop:include name="loggerAspect"/>
</aop:aspectj-autoproxy>

<aop:config>
  <!-- Beans -->
  <aop:aspect id="loggerAspect" ref="loggerAspectBean">
    <!-- Pointcuts -->
    <aop:pointcut id="loggerPointcut" expression="execution(* foo.Bar.baz(..))"/>
    <!-- Advice -->
    <aop:around method="log" pointcut-ref="loggerPointcut"/>
  </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>

<bean id="loggerAspectBean" class="foo.LoggerAspect"></bean>
```

In my pom, is a Maven project, i have spring-aop, aspectjrt and aspectjweaver as dependencies.

My problem is that when launching the app I get a `ClassNotFoundException` for `foo.LoggerAspect`, which is comprehensible because `foo.LoggerAspect` is an aspectj aspect, not a java class.

So my question is:

- How should I configure Spring so it uses aspectj aspects written in a `.aj` file?

Annotations aren't possible here, aspects are a given and cannot modify them and need to preserve the configuration by XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok simple solution, just compile the `aj` files with the ajc compiler and you get a class file (if you compile for LTW) and then the class is found. And adding `<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on"/>` did the rest.